# getting error "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h" file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, cocoapods

I am trying to build a Cocoapod xcode project. I followed below steps to configure cocoapods on my mac machine(MAC OS yosemite 10.10.2, xcode 6.1.1 version)

- sudo gem update --system
- sudo gem install cocoapods
- pod setup
- and then navigated to existing cocoapod xcode project root directory 
  entered pod update

Now while opening xcode workspace file, am getting the below error in projectname-Prefix.pch file

"ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h" file not found (but I see library and class file in the project)

Comment: are u using swift or objectiveC

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Code is written in Objective-C

Comment: do u see ReactiveCocoa.h in pods section and have u tried pod install instead of pod update.

Comment: could u show your podfile content ?

Comment: Here is the podfile content podfile contentplatform :ios, "7.0"

pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 2.2.4'
pod 'ReactiveViewModel', '~> 0.2'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.2.0'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 1.8.1'
pod 'SSKeychain', '~> 1.2.1'
pod 'MagicalRecord', '~> 2.2'
pod 'WYPopoverController', '~> 0.2.0'

Comment: have u tried using bridging header file?

Comment: no...can u plz provide more detail...am trying to compile an existing working ios cocoapod projet.

Comment: using ObjC or swift ?

Comment: would like to invite u to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73555/discussion-for-cocoapods

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was resolved like this way..

```
After opening terminal -> Goto the project directory

cd /Your Xcode Project Directory Path

Press Enter.
```

Now use this command to check if there is any update available for existing pods.

```
pod outdated
```

It will show all the outdated pods with latest updates

Now use the following command to update the outdated pods.

```
pod update
```

It will update all the pods automatically.

Make sure that you have closed the Xcode before updating.

After updating change the import section of your class files.

```
#import <ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h>
```

Thanks.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I solved it by adding the ReactiveCocoa framework to TARGETS -> General -> Linked frameworks and libraries, then error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond updating the import to (like @onCompletion mentioned above):

```
#import <ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h>
```

also add this to your target's "Header Search Paths":

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/ReactiveCocoa"
```

If it still doesn't works, also add this to your target's "Other Linker Flags":

```
-l"ReactiveCocoa"
```